# Python: configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'settings'

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

After converting a selenium script to a .exe file using pyinstaller, I am getting below error during the .exe file execution.

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S5.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "configparser.py", line 781, in get
  File "configparser.py", line 1141, in _unify_values
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'settings'
```

I am able to execute the .py file successfully. 
This issue only appears when executing the .exe file.

Below part of the S5.py Script:

```html
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from configparser import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read('myini.ini')

A = parser.get('settings', 'company')
B = parser.get('settings', 'user')
C = parser.get('settings', 'password')
D = parser.get('settings', 'system')
E = parser.get('settings', 'driver')
F = parser.get('settings', 'file1')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(E)
driver.get(D) 
driver.maximize_window()

#Access
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtCmpCd"]').send_keys(A) 
driver.find_element_by_name('txtUserCd').send_keys(B)
```

Below the .ini file:

```html
[settings]
company = ABC
user = John
password = 1234
system = https://website.com
driver = C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe
file1 = C:/Users/john/Desktop/abc.xls
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix the issue and generate the .exe file successfully after passing the full path of the .ini file in the python script:

before: parser.read('myini.ini')

after: parser.read('C:/Users/john/Desktop/myini.ini')

Answer (score 0):

Providing the path of the file did not help me.
I carried the .ini file to the project root and provided '../config.ini' as the path. BTW I am using a MAC.

[image]